# How to get the number of mysql updates per second with collectd?

Tags: mysql, collectd

The man page for the [mysql plugin](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:MySQL) states that the values are per second, but I've set up an HTTP server for the `write_http` plugin and I receive strings like `PUTVAL r6/mysql-wormly_shm/mysql_commands-update interval=2 1336122875:6279`, where 6279 is the total number of updates.

How do I get the numbers per second?